# Carbon dioxide concentration from pressure changes

Tags: gas-laws

Is there a way of determining the concentration of CO<sub>2</sub> if we know the pressure in the container before the addition of CO<sub>2</sub> and the pressure in the container after the addition of CO<sub>2</sub> if we have no way of measuring the amount of CO<sub>2</sub> delivered to the container (like with a CO<sub>2</sub> controller with a CO<sub>2</sub> monitor)? For instance, if we have a sealed container with air in it at 298 K, whose pressure is measured at 1 atm, and we introduce carbon dioxide gas causing the pressure to increase to 1.2 atm... can we use the ideal gas equation and assume that the 0.2 atm increase is due to addition of CO<sub>2</sub> and is the partial pressure of CO<sub>2</sub> and just use 0.2 atm/(0.0821 × 298) = 0.008 m/L (approx. 352 ppm) as the concentration of the CO<sub>2</sub> in the chamber? Or, is there more to it?

Comment: The m/L is correct, but how did you get that 352 ppm?

Comment: I was working on the molecular mass of carbon dioxide being about 44g/mol and 1M = 44g/L and so 44000 ppm, so 44000 x 0.008 = 352... is that correct?

Comment: That would be the grams per liter.  The mole fraction of CO2 is 1/6, and the mole fraction of air is 5/6.  So, on a molecule basis, the ppm CO2 is 167000.  What is it on a mass basis?

Comment: I found this: "To convert from ppm by mass to ppm by volume, divide by the density of the particles." so I am assuming I will need to determine the density of the carbon dioxide and will also need to know the volume of the container.

Comment: Not really.  I know that it may not make sense, but in common terminology, ppm volume means 1 million times the mole fraction.  So you won't need to know the volume of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the partial pressures of the gases, then you can calculate the mass fractions.  In the present case, assume you have 1 mole of gas.  Then the number of moles of CO2 is 0.167 moles and the number of moles of air is 0.833.  The mass of CO2 is (44)(0.167)=7.33 grams and the mass of air is (29)(0.833)=24.2 grams.  So the mass fraction of CO2 is $$\frac{7.33}{(7.33+24.2)}=0.233$$
So the ppm CO2 by volume = 167000 and the ppm CO2 by mass = 233000.

Comment: That's great! Thank you, Chet. This makes perfect sense and I will be able to apply this to the problem I am trying to solve!